# Basics of Mumford stability

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $(E, X)$ be a holomorphic vector bundle of rank 2 over a compact Kähler manifold. Prove that if it's neither a direct sum nor slope stable then it has a unique sub-bundle which is a counterexample to its slope stability. Why $E$ is a canonical extension of that sub-bundle?

I think an answer to this question will describe the fact that slope is related to ampleness. If not, I highly appreciate it if someone can relate them with mathematical knowledge of 1962.

if it helps, It's the item (iv) of basic properties of Mumford stability in Mumford's 1962 ICM lecture[1, page 529]. Although the article is more general I only need this case.

1. Mumford, D. "Projective invariants of projective structures and applications 1963 Proc." Internat. Congr. Mathematicians (Stockholm, 1962) pp: 526-530.